# How can I increase my ship's powergrid?

Tags: eve-online

My power grid is maxed out for what I'm trying to fit to my ship, but only just. My engineering level is already at level 5 so I can't get more powergrid out of levelling this further.

I was wondering, are there any other skills, implants or equipment I can fit to my ship to further increase my ship's powergrid output?

Comment: If we are talking about smaller ships, which I assume since BS etc have enough grid, the cheapest and probably fastest way should be a Micro Auxiliary Power Core. It is cheap and adds a lot of pg.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main skill that affects power grid is Engineering, but there are several others that affect the PG requirements of specific modules or rigs:

- Shield Upgrades (affects PG need of Shield extender and passive resistance modules)
- Advanced Weapon Upgrades (affects PG need of weapons)
- Projectile/Hybrid/Energy weapons rigging (reduces PG need increase due to weapons rigs)

The main implant that increases PG is the Inherent Implants 'Squire' Engineering EG series, which provides a 1-6% increase in total powergrid. The 1% version is extremely afforable even if you lose your pod often, but one significant drawback is that the implants for powergrid and CPU use the same slot, so you can't upgrade both with implants at the same time.

The Genolution Core Augmentation implant set is another way to boost PG. The CA-1 provides a 1.5% PG increase, and together with the CA-2 it also receives a 50% set bonus. You can fit these implants in addition to the Squire Engineering one.

There is also the Zainou 'Gnome' Shield Upgrades SU implant series which reduces the PG requirements of modules that require the Shield Upgrades skill by 1-6%, but that is a rather niche benefit and probably only useful in very rare cases.

There are several modules that increase power grid:

- Micro Auxiliary power core (+10MW/+12MW, especially useful for frigates as it is a fixed PG bonus and not a percentage of total PG. Useless on big ships)
- Reactor Control Unit (+10%/+15% total PG)
- Power diagnostic system (+5% PG, but additional shield and capacitor bonuses)
- Ancillary current router rigs (+10%/+15%, but more expensive than most other rigs)

Answer (score 2):

[Advanced Weapon Upgrades](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Advanced_Weapon_Upgrades) gets you 2% reduction in powergrid for turrets and launchers.
[Shield Upgrades](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Shield_Operation) is 5% for anything requiring the Shield Upgrades skill.

Implant-wise there is [a hardwiring set](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Item_Database:Implants_&_Boosters:Implants:Skill_Hardwiring:Implant_Slot_6:Engineering_Implants) in the 6 slot that gives PG (conveniently named 'Squire' PG(X)).

Equipment wise you have two options:
1. Find modules on your fitting you can switch out for other meta levels that require less PG to fit. This generally means finding a specific meta level, or going for shiny mods such as faction, complex or officer mods.
2. Fit a [Power Diagnostic System](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Item_Database:Ship_Equipment:Engineering_Equipment:Power_Diagnostic_Systems) or [Reactor Control Unit](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Item_Database:Ship_Equipment:Engineering_Equipment:Reactor_Control_Units) in a low slot. PDS gives a small boost to many things, with RCU is a big boost to PG.